# How to view CiviCRM Event Participants Custom Participant Fields?

Tags: civievent, profile, custom-fields, search

We have an event and need to track any special dietary needs for attendees. I have created a custom field 'Dietary Needs' for event participants. This works as expected.

HOWEVER, the only way that I can view the dietary needs is by viewing the event registration for a single individual. I need a way to view the attendees in a list along with any participant custom fields.

What is the best way to do this? Search views do not seem to work with participant fields (Participant can not be used as a Result Column for profile searches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the settings of your custom field and ensure that "Is this field searchable?" is checked.

Overall it sounds like you're looking for a list or basic report. Run the Attendee List and you can add your custom field from the Columns section (but only if you've made it searchable).

Comment: Yes, the field is searchable. I ended up doing a report as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using the Event Participant Report (List) and selecting my custom field for display.